# How to serve static files with Waitress and Django?

Tags: python, django, reverse-proxy, web-deployment, waitress

I've a tiny web app built on Django that has some static files collected by `python manage.py collectstatic`. I'm using a lightweight server, [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/)

When I run my server using the script

```
from waitress import serve

from <my app>.wsgi import application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve(application, host = '0.0.0.0', port='8000')
```

the app loads up to `http:localhost:8000` but I notice the static files are not present. From the terminal, I can read

```
Not Found: /static/<my app>/styles.min.css
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /static/<my app>/styles.min.css
Not Found: /static/<my app>/buttonhover.css
WARNING:django.request:Not Found: /static/<my app>/buttonhover.css
Not Found: /static/<my app>/script.min.js
```

Do I need something in addition to Waitress to serve the static files? Do I need a reverse proxy like nginx running alongside Waitress? If so, are there Python reverse proxies available?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/
You can use reverse proxy for wsgi server and directly serve static files through nginix

Comment: @iklinac yeah, I figured that I would need something like nginx, I just happen to work on a Windows server and really don't want to go out of my way to setup nginx for an internal web app. Would there be a problem hosting the files on AWS S3, and skipping nginx altogether? Or would this create future problems?

Comment: If you read documentation provided in link you would see there is an option for that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution using the [White Noise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#) library.

> Do I need something in addition to Waitress to serve the static files?

Yes. Kinda. You do need something to help Django find the static files, or upload them to a container online like AWS S3.

> Do I need a reverse proxy like nginx running alongside Waitress?

No. White Noise is a simple add on to a Django project which in my opinion pairs it well with [Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/stable/) since they're self-contained Python projects.